# Symfony2: How do i validate an object/array with its constraints in another object/array?

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-validator

It's built dynamically, annotations are not an option. I have the constraints in an array.

It seems you need to manually construct the validator but I get stuck fast on the point where you need to construct a MetaDataFactory that needs an loader, but all the loaders have the job of loading meta data from a file.. I dont think I'm doing it right.

Simply said:

I have an array/object with keys/values. I want them validated by another array that contains the constraints.

It's not possible to iterate over the keys and call validate on each and every one of them, since some rely on the context values from other keys.

```
$array = [
  'key1' => 'abc',
  'key2' => 'def',
];

$constraints = [
  'key1' => new All([
    new Constraint..,
    new CallbackConstraint.., // <- this one checks key2 for its value      
  ]),
  'key2' => new NotBlank
];
```

I can also build one array containing both.

Againt, the object/array is built dynamically, i cant validate the container itself. It's about the keys inside it that are definitions on its own.

So what i basically would want is:

```
$validator->validate($array, $constraints);
```

<s>I can imagine you need a custom MetaDataFactory / Loader / Context class or something, the problem is simply that the callback validator needs to access `$this->getRoot()` to get to the other values</s>

Nevermind that, you would need something like a CallbackLoader in which you create your own properties => constraints mapping. But the LoaderInterface requires a concrete implementation of ClassMetaData, which on his own has no way of dealing with arrays or ArrayObjects, unless you have methods/properties on that ArrayObject. But--since my container is built dynamically, i can't have that. Method methods are not an option because of the property/method_exists calls.

Comment: The keys of the array are the same always (i.e. not change)? else, why you don't use `class/object` instead of `array`? currently, the target of constraint must be a class, method or property of class: http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#constraint-targets

Comment: However, you can use `Callback` or `Expression` constraints to validate the whole data as `array`

Comment: @Yonel ill see if i can get it working with the constraint targets